# How negative Hessian of Hamiltonian implies strict convexity?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $X$ be a strictly convex domain in a Riemannian manifold $(\tilde{X}, g)$ of dimension $\geq 3$ with boundary defining function $\rho$ (so $\rho \in C^{\infty}(\tilde{X}), \rho>0$ in $X,<0$ on $\tilde{X} \backslash \bar{X}$, vanishes non-degenerately at $\partial X)$. We recall that strict convexity means that geodesics which are tangent to $\partial X$ are only simply tangent, curving away from $X$.

I do not understand how follwoing implies strict convexity?

Consider $G$ the dual metric function on $T^{*} \tilde{X}$, if for some $\beta \in T_{p}^{*} \tilde{X}, p \in \partial X, \beta \neq 0$, one has $\left(H_{G} \rho\right)(\beta)=0$ where $H_{G}$ is the Hamiltonian vector field associated with $G$, then necessarily $\left(H_{G}^{2} \rho\right)(\beta)<0$.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.